# Weeding out polygons in collision tests

Tags: graphics, collision-detection

I am creating a collision detection system whose near-phase collision detection involves checking the triangles of one shape against those of another. I have run into the problem that this is an expensive process. Is there any way I can "weed out" triangles that just definitely do not intersect before I begin the triangle-triangle collision detection?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the screen into sections.  Each triangle can be in up to 4 sections, but knows which ones it's in.  Then you only have to deal with the other triangles in the same section(s).  This greatly reduces the number of comparisons you have to do.

Comment: Which data structure would be best for that? I've looked at kd trees, bps trees, an octrees and from what I can tell they aren't good for a dynamic scene like mine. This is a 3D scene, by the way.

Comment: How about a three dimensional array of linked lists?  Each cell would represent a section of the scene (or multiple sections with wraparound if the space is not fixed).  The linked list would have all the triangles in that section and is optimized for easy adding and removal as things change.  You might try a linked list of the containing objects as well--the main idea is to exclude all triangles that are impossibly far away.